# What is the process for registering an application phone number to send SMS messages on Twilio?

Tags: twilio, sms

I have an application that sends SMS messages to users that opt-in using the Twilio platform. Recently the US started blocking numbers that are not A2P 10DLC registered, requiring all numbers to undergo registration in order to send messages.
Does anyone know the process for properly registering numbers in Twilio and that can offer to do it for me? (Inc. renumeration)

I tried applying for a registration myself, but the system is still showing as unregistrered, while a proper submission would return a Pending-Registration status.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the 10 DLC within the Twilio Console [here](https://www.twilio.com/console/trust-hub/a2p-messaging/wizard)

PS: This article should hopefully answer all questions regarding the [10 DLC Registration](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260801864489-How-do-I-register-to-use-A2P-10DLC-messaging-)